# How can I load my existing characters looks into character creation?

Tags: black-desert-online

I have already created one character and made it exactly how I wanted to look. However, after playing for a few hours and getting to around level 15, I've decided that I'm not really feeling tamer, and would like to try out another class.

I saw in the character creation screen that you could save and load file, but during creation I didn't do this. Is there a way for me to copy the design of my existing character into a file so I can load it up into character creation for the new character I'd like to make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By choosing the Beauty option in-game, you can save your current character's customization to a file.

[image]

This will load up the character creation screen that you're familiar with, where you can click save file in the bottom left.